# Backup cache on pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, caching

My app uses data stored in cache, no more than 30MB at any instant. This data is important, so I would prefer not to loose it on unwanted crashes or recycles. Is there any method or way to make a backup of this data in SQL Server when the app recycles? Is there any method which is called when the app recycles where I can make a backup on SQL Server when that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code to save your data to file or database in global.asax in Application_End(). In a polite shutdown that should get called.

There are some instances when Application_End event will not be fired when there is not a polite shutdown. These are covered [here](http://forums.asp.net/669457/ShowPost.aspx) and summarized below:

> This event fires when a live application is gracefully shutdown. The
>   following things can cause this event to fire:
>
> 1. You edit the config file for an application that's running. This causes ASP.NET to unload the app and reload it, so Application_End
>      will fire
> 2. You change a dll in the bin directory. This also causes ASP.NET to unload the app and reload it, so Application_End will fire
> 3. You stop (or restart) IIS
> 4. If you have any sort of Process Recycling turned on either in IIS6 App Pools, or using the aspnet worker process, then when that process
>      recycles the Application_End event will fire for all active
>      applications
> 5. Any other similar event that causes processes to gracefully restart.
>
> It does NOT fire when a process doesn't gracefully exit - like it's
>   deadlocked and needs to be killed. Also It does NOT fire when all live
>   sessions have ended, although all active sessions will end before the
>   application ends in the above scenarios. The subtle difference is that
>   all live sessions can end but the app is still running idle.

Comment: I've seen cases where the IIS process stops and you don't get the shutdown events. In normal cases, the IIS recycling or an IISReset should politely inform the application pool that it's being shut down and you'll get the event.